# Adding Native Image Resources in Cordova (Intel XDK)

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, intel-xdk

I'm new to Cordova/Intel XDK I am trying to use the [ThemeableBrowser](https://github.com/initialxy/cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser) plugin, which says that images referenced must be "native image resources." I'm having trouble adding such resources. The ReadMe for the plugin says

> First of all, your native iOS and Android projects are located at:
>
> /platforms/ios
>   /platforms/android

I did not find those directories in my project.(project type HTML5+Cordova). So, I created them in Explorer.

The instructions go on to say to make drawable resource folders in

> /platforms/android/res

So I did that. But the features still are not working and my build size has not increased, so I don't think these resources are being considered. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that plugin is not supported in the XDK at this time.

More details can be found here:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/562433